# Retrieving width and height from a bmp

Tags: c#, drawing, bmp

I have a few .bmp images inside a directory and want to loop through them to see if the width and height are of a certain amount. Since I am not using a webform, I can not use, `using System.drawing;` How the initial code looked like was,

```
 string[] temp = Directory.GetFiles(link);
            string[] localImages = extractHeroImages(temp);

            for (int i = 0; i < localImages.Length; i++)
            {
               Bitmap img = new Bitmap(localImages[i]);
                if (img.Height != 185 || img.Width != 185)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Error: " + numErrors + " /n current width of     " + localImages[i] + " is: " + img.Width + " height is: " + img.Height + "\n");
                    numErrors++;
                }
            }
```

This code worked when I was working on a web form of this program but when I wanted to create a utility for it, it crashed on this part of the code and can not find a way around it.
Is there a way I can get the width and height without using a webform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with a webform, your problem seems to be the path you're giving to the `Bitmap` constructor

Comment: You can use System.Drawing where you want...anyway what's the error???

Comment: The name "bitmap" could not be found, so it had to be the importing

Comment: I can't use system.Drawing since this is a console appilcation

Comment: Of course you can use System.Drawing.  Use Project + Add Reference.  For future reference, a compile error is *not* a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add the System.Drawing dll to the project. Just right click the project in the Solution explorer and select `Add Reference...`.